# can i automate this twilio verified phone numbers list from a python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-python

[image: want to autofill this list (verified phone numbers) from a python progam]

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import os
account_sid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

mob = 'XXXXXXXXXX'

verify = client.verify.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
verify.verifications.create(to=mob, channel='sms')

n = int(input('enter code: '))
result = verify.verification_checks.create(to=mob, code=n)
print(result.status)
```

after verifying the phone number i want to add that phone number to my twilio verified phone numbers lisI. I want to know if it is possible or not..[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this by using the [Twilio Voice API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/):

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
validation_request = client.validation_requests \
                           .create(
                               friendly_name='A friendly name',
                               phone_number='+1234567890'
                           )
print(validation_request.validation_code)
```

Taken and adapted from the Twilio documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/outgoing-caller-ids#add-an-outgoing-caller-id).

Note:

> This will create a new CallerID validation request within Twilio, which initiates a call to the phone number provided and listens for a validation code.

And:

> Adding an Outgoing Caller ID via the API has the same result as [verifying a number](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified) via the Twilio console.

Comment: Yes, but when i had run so it gives me this -> "Sorry! Placing verification calls is not supported on trial accounts. Please upgrade to a full account first". I think, there is no option to automate from a free trial account :-}.